# Using an Enum as a Template Object in Javascript (GAS)

Tags: javascript, object, enums, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that contains about 60-some columns as the result of the form submission. Currently I am storing "column X means Y" in ScriptProperties (Google Apps Script):

`Key` "timestamp"
`Value` 0

This is so that I have a meaningful reference to column indices by variable name instead of a non-meaningful number, but currently this results in ~60 API calls which slows down execution a bit.

I would like to create an **enum** of the column indices for the entire spreadsheet, since it will remain static, like this:

```
var formResults = {
  timestamp: 0,
  firstName: 1,
  lastName: 2,
  ...
  status: 60
}
```

That way I don't have to reference script properties (slows execution by calling the API). The next thing I want to do, assuming that I have this `formResults` variable initialized at the start of the script, is to create a new object which represents a `row` in the spreadsheet. I.e.:

```
for (allRows in sheet) {
  var rowData = new Object(formResults);
}
```

I hope my goal is coming across - I want to use the `enum` to create a new `object` using all of the enum's values. The enum could be a *template* for a new object being formed from the data in each row.

I know that I can iterate through each row, then subsequently each column of the spreadsheet and do:

```
var row = row_in_spreadsheet; // row[0] = first column of the row for instance

var rowData = {
  timestamp: row[formResults.timestamp], // row[0]
  firstName: row[formResults.firstName], // row[1]
  lastName: row[formResults.lastName], // row[2]
  ...
  status: row[formResults.status] // row[60]
}
```

I would rather not have 60 lines of code for creating one object... is there any way that I can use the indices in the enum as a *template* for creating a new object from the data in each row? Or is the last bit of code the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can *enum*erate the properties of your `enum` object using a [for-in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (var i=0; i<allRows; i++) {
    var row = sheet[i]; // or whatever you use to iterate the rows

    var rowData = {};
    for (var key in formResults)
        rowData[key] = row[formResults[key]];

    // now do anything with your rowData
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant... I just *knew* there was a way to do it! Thanks so much, made my code a **lot** easier to read and manage haha. Not to mention more efficient :)